# Open and closed functions, is there an equivalent, easier way to check?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I know that an open function is a function that maps every open set of the domain to some open set. So it is easy to prove that a function is not open just by giving a counter example. However, I have some difficulties while checking whether a function is open or not, since there are lots of different types of open sets, especially in a metric space. In particular, even in $\mathbb{R}$ there are lots of open sets, not only intervals I mean. Here is my question, Is it possible to change the condition to have some equivalent one. For instance, would it be sufficient to check only open balls, or closed balls for closed mappings. My question is general, so I ask the same for closed maps. Thanks!

Comment: It's sufficient to check the condition for a subbasis of the domain's topology, because then finite intersections and arbitrary unions of images of the subbasis elements also will be open.

Comment: A union (even an infinite union) of open sets is open.  So, can you show that $f$ is open by checking it only on a base for the topology?

Comment: @RobertShore The image of an intersection need not be the intersection of the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For open sets it is enough to check it for open balls (or any family of sets such that every open set is a union of some members of the family).

For closed sets such  a criterion usually fails. For example the map $(x,y) \to x$ from $\mathbb R^{2}$ to $\mathbb R$  maps closed balls to closed sets, but it is not a closed map since the image of $\{(x,y): xy=1\}$ is not closed.

Comment: I get why it fails for closed sets, however isn't it possilbe to find such a condition that is given for open sets?

Comment: I said 'usaully fails' to indicate that no such criterion is usually possible For example,  it is not enough to check it for compact sets. The problem here is infinite unions of closed sets are not closed except in some trivial cases.  @BerkYıldız